# Did Jesus forseeing the different Denominational division of the Church, unify them together into the Kingdom of God in John 3:16?

Tags: exegesis, biblical-basis

Recently the number of Denominations, who claim to be the true Church; has caused me to research the Bible in search of Jesus description of the church, and the restrictions associated with its membership.

The only Scripture which I feel covers this is:

> John 3:16 and 17  KJV For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life. 17  For God sent not his Son into the world to condemn the world; but that the world through him might be saved.

If there are other Scriptures which can help in my quest I would appreciate having them. Please do not restrict answers to any particular translation as I appreciate any input from any version of the scriptures.

Thank you for your help and consideration.